# Why does 'which' give incorrect result?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, environment-variables

I am executing on a Ubuntu 12.04 shell the following command:

```
sudo bash -c "echo $PATH; which python"
```

which displays something like

```
/home/me/env/develop/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
/usr/bin/python
```

and the following command

```
ls /home/me/env/develop/bin
```

displys (amont others)

```
python
```

According to the `man` pages the `which` command looks for the given executable in all paths defined in `PATH`. The `man` page does not strictly specify the 'order' of the search, but usually it goes from the start to the end of the `PATH` environment variable.

Now, the path `/home/me/env/develop/bin` contains a python executable (modes set correctly, not a symbolic link), which is also the first path  in `PATH`. But the `which` command displays a completly different location!

Why is that? I am doing something stupid? Has it magically to do with `sudo`? Is this a bug?

Comment: use the bash builtin `type` instead of `which`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. `$PATH` within the double quotes gets expanded by your shell before `bash -c` even sees it.

This means, you'll actually run:

```
sudo bash -c "echo /home/me/env/develop/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games; which python"
```

Small test:

```
$ foo="hello"
$ sudo bash -c "echo $foo"
hello
```

To get to the root of your problem, run:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH; which python'
```

This won't expand `$PATH` before.

A solution for your path issue would be to set the path in your `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`—that is if I'm assuming correctly your path is set there—so that it is loaded even for non-login shells (as in `bash -c`). Or you run `bash -lc` to have it run a login shell instead, which would load `.bash_profile`.